# Is it possible to use a portable wifi router as a mobile network extender?

Tags: router

The network in my area is terrible. I got a few places in the house where I get a decent network and it is in places where I can't comfortably use my devices. Moreover, I want to be able to use the mobile network anywhere inside my home. I have a Samsung portable mini router than uses a sim. I was wondering if it is possible for me to use it as a network extender. So I can place the router in places where the network is strong enough and use my mobile phone anywhere easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend the mobile network, but you might create a WiFi network with better coverage.

Instead of conventional phone calls you can use various voip tools (messenger, Viber, Skype...)